# Pandas - How to fill empty values with whatever value defined above

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of the input:

[image]

Here is an example of the output:

[image]

Comment: You are looking for ffill(axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

If 'Col1' and 'Col2' are indexex,

```
df.reset_index()
```

If not then

```
df.ffill()
```